# How one can share post from flutter app to social media platforms like inkedIn, facebook and etc?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I want to share post from my flutter app to social media platforms like linkedIn and face book. How do I do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flutter [Share Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share).

```
Share.share('Your content here.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) for redirect user to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about linkedin but for facebook, you can use [social_share_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/social_share_plugin). In addition to the instructions on the readme, I also followed the example by adding provider_paths.xml in android/app/src/main/res/xml. You need to make sure you're using the latest facebook SDK implementation so in android/app/build.gradle, add the following code to dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) package.

```
String response;
String url = 'https://cardaji.com';
String msg = "Look my great score on cardaji";
String strSeparator=" \n";
final FlutterShareMe flutterShareMe = FlutterShareMe();
// facebook post
response = await flutterShareMe.shareToFacebook(url: url, msg: msg);

// twitter post
response = await flutterShareMe.shareToTwitter(url: url, msg: msg);

// whatsapp post
response = await flutterShareMe.shareToTelegram(msg: msg+ strSeparator+ url);

// telegram post
response = await flutterShareMe.shareToWhatsApp(msg: msg+strSeparator+url);
```

**Very Important**

When you build your iOS project, you can find the following errors in sharefacebook function of SwiftFlutterShareMePlugin.swift file.

> 'init()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
> (FBSDKShareKit.ShareDialog)

```
func sharefacebook(message:Dictionary<String,Any>, result: @escaping FlutterResult)  {
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    let shareDialog=ShareDialog() // **this line make the error**
    let shareContent = ShareLinkContent()
    shareContent.contentURL = URL.init(string: message["url"] as! String)!
    shareContent.quote = message["msg"] as? String
    shareDialog.mode = .automatic
    ShareDialog(fromViewController: viewController, content: shareContent, delegate: self).show()
    result("Sucess")
    
}
```

It is because facebook sdk is upgraded, so you can update SwiftFlutterShareMePlugin.swift of [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) package(version 1.2.0) file as following.

```
func sharefacebook(message:Dictionary<String,Any>, result: @escaping FlutterResult)  {
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    
    let shareContent = ShareLinkContent()
    shareContent.contentURL = URL.init(string: message["url"] as! String)!
    shareContent.quote = message["msg"] as? String
    ShareDialog(viewController: viewController, content: shareContent, delegate: self).show()
    result("Sucess")
    
}
```

Comment: @persec100000 It is fixed the iOS build issue but it does not share to facebook. I got success from response and facebook app is installed and login. Facebook app not open.

Comment: But I am using flutter_share_me: ^1.2.0 and this error is still there.